# Convert formulas in table to structural references

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have converted my range in excel 2010 into a table. However, the formulas which were before like that(see below) stayed the same and do not convert into structural references.

`=IF(AND(ROUND($GX19-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0;$AK$7=1);0;$M$12*$M$22/$K$62`

Any recommendations how to automatically convert them into structural references?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Did you convert the range with formula into the table as well?

Comment: Nope, just converted the whole range into a table. The problem is that the whole range is a table, but still the references do not automatically convert into a structural table references...

Comment: If the formulas are near the table, try converting them with the range into the table, they *might* convert to structured references by doing that, I'm not sure.

Comment: related from SE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839423/convert-automatically-excel-table-formulas-from-explicit-cell-reference-to-struc

Answer (score 1):

I would edit the formula in the first (non-heading) row of the table.  I would select each cell reference and then select the relevant column - that will replace the cell reference with a column reference.

This is a bit painful to do, although there are nice visual guides of which reference points where.

Once you have done this in one row, that change will be copied down to all rows in the table.